# How to change the timing on the screensaver

Tags: screensaver

How can I change the timing of when the screensaver kicks in?
The time period set in the screensaver to kick in is too short and I would like to change this timing period to a larger value.
How does one do that?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running gnome it's done using 'gnome-control-center' and selecting the 'Screen' option.

A bit hard to know if this is the answer for you with so little information given.